# How to specify type for class constrained value?

Tags: haskell, yesod, typeclass, persistent, monad-transformers

I'm trying to use a type signature on the result of the following `persistent` call. I can't figure out how to define the signature for something that's parameterized and class constrained such as the `m` inside of the transformer below:

```
saveMyStuff :: MonadIO m => Int -> SqlPersistT m Stuff
saveMyStuff somethingId = do
  -- 1. this works with ScopedTypeVariables
  (_ :: [Entity MyEntity]) <- rawSql "SELECT ?? FROM my_entities WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE" 
                                     [toPersistValue somethingId]
  -- 2. this doesn't :(
  _ <- rawSql "SELECT ?? FROM my_entities WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE" 
              [toPersistValue somethingId]
              :: SqlPersistT m [Entity MyEntity]
```

How do I use the latter approach? Is 2. at all solvable without extensions? What would I change that signature to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't realize you needed to repeat constraints inside of functions as well. This worked:

```
_ <- rawSql "SELECT ?? FROM my_entities WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE" 
          [toPersistValue somethingId]
          :: MonadIO m => SqlPersistT m [Entity MyEntity]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `forall` to the type signature:

```
saveMyStuff :: forall m. MonadIO m => Int -> SqlPersistT m Stuff
```

When using [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables), variables are only scoped when they are explicitly introduced with `forall`.

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out how to make 2. from my example work without the use of ScopedTypeVariables, sorry if the question wasn't super clear.

Comment: @AlexandrKurilin 2. should work if you do what I wrote in the answer, sorry if I wasn't clear.